# git batch rename bulk of commited files

Tags: git

I have a git repo with bulk (thousands) of some files commited. I want to rename it with batch command line command, something like

```
git mv *.txt *.md
```

But got the `fatal: bad source, source=*.txt, destination=*.md` message.

How to rename commited files with git cli?

Answer (score 3):

Git does not support this out of the box, but you can use your shell's features to perform the task:

```sh
for file in *.txt; do
  git mv "$file" "${file%.txt}.md";
done
```

`${file%.txt}.md` will expand the `file` variable, strip its `.txt` extension and then append `.md` after its value.

Comment: My variant for windows batch is a `for %x in (*.txt) do ( git mv %~nx.txt %~nx.md )`

Answer (score 3):

For maximum CPU efficiency, Git's core `update-index` command can take bulk updates on stdin:

```
git ls-files -s \*.txt \
| sed -r 's,([^ ]* )(.*)\.txt,0 \2.txt\n\1\2.md,' \
| git update-index --index-info
```

which will do the index update in one pass.  Then you can get `git read-tree` to do your work tree updates in a single pass with

```
newtree=`git write-tree`
git read-tree @
git read-tree -u --reset @ $newtree
```

The `sed` converts the index entries `git ls -s` dumped into two index updates, a deletion (mode 0) entry for the old `*.txt` name and an insert for the new `*.md` one.  `git read-tree` is the core command underlying checkout and merge and a lot of other bulk work-tree updaters, the sequence above is "write a tree for the index, reset it to its state at checkout, then read the new tree back in and update the work tree to match as if we were doing a checkout or fast-forward merge".

---

edit: for maximum convenience, you can instead

```
find -name \*.txt -execdir rename .txt .md {} +
git add -A .
```

which will also pick up whatever other changes you might have in the work tree; this is less "safe", you might not want any other changes added or your `.gitignore` might not be all that well tuned yet, but if your build's clean this is likely to save more typing time than it costs in make-Git-figure-it-all-out time.

Comment: It should be noted that this uses the util-linux rename which is common on Fedora-based systems; for systems like Debian, which use the Perl-based rename, you should use `find -name \*.txt -execdir rename 's/.txt$/.md/' {} +` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Changing files extension**

If you have a lot of files with a particular file extension, and you want to change it to another compatible extension, you can use the following command:

```
ren *.ext1 *.ext2
```

Command syntax **example**:

```
ren *.txt *.md
```

The command syntax example changes the .txt file extension to .md format of all the files in the folder.

**Renaming files with a specific file extension**

`ren nyc_*.* newYork_*.*`

above command will rename all files in the folder. If you want to rename only images files with a .jpg extension, you can use the following command:

```
 ren nyc_*.jpg newYork_*.jpg.
```

**Renaming multiple files**

To rename multiple files, use this command syntax:

```
ren *.ext1 ???-new_filename_part.*
```

Command syntax example:

```
ren *.jpg ???-hikingTrip.*
```

Comment: After this you still need  to tell git about all old files and all new files, so you would need to run `git rm '*.txt' && git add *.md` (`*.txt` in quotes so that the shell does not expand the wildcard and Git can make use of it. Not sure if this even works, would have to try) – this question is specifically about bulk renaming (tracked) files in/with Git

Comment: Batch extension changing is obvious. Question is about git

Answer (score 0):

Git has no built in "batch rename" operation, but it doesn't matter: you can do the batch rename however you like, then `git add` the new names and `git add -u` to pick up the removal of (all) the old names, or just `git add` the old names individually.  That is:

```
$ git mv old new
```

has the exact same effect as:

```
$ mv old new
$ git add old new
```

To demonstrate, I have actually run the above two commands in a temporary test repository, and now I run `git status`:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        renamed:    old -> new
```

---

[knittl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56282371/1256452) is fine, of course, but I'd also like to show how I tend to do tasks this myself:

```
$ echo *.txt | sed 's/\(.*\).txt/git mv \1.txt \1.md/'
git mv a.txt b.txt a.txt b.md
```

*Oops, that was wrong, I need one file name per line ... let's try this:*

```
$ printf %s\\n *.txt | sed 's/\(.*\).txt/git mv \1.txt \1.md/'
git mv a.txt a.md
git mv b.txt b.md
```

*There, that's what I wanted, now to actually do it, type control-P and add `| sh`:*

```
$ printf %s\\n *.txt | sed 's/\(.*\).txt/git mv \1.txt \1.md/' | sh
```

In other words, I like to write a one line script to generate the commands that should be run, then re-run the one-line script with output redirected into a pipe feeding `sh` to run them.  If the one line script gets me most of the way, but a few cases need hand-tweaking, I replace the `| sh` with `> /tmp/doit.sh`, then edit the `/tmp/doit.sh` script to do the hand-tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, Git Bash, for me worked following in order to change extension .css to .scss

```
find . -name "*.css" -exec sh -c 'git mv "$1" "${1%.css}.scss"' _ {} \;
```